# How to open pop-up windows using AWS Lambda which can be invoked from AWS Lex?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

We were trying to open a pop-up window using Lambda Function. For example, if we want to open "https://www.google.com/" we used the following python code

```
import json
import webbrowser as wb

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    wb.open_new_tab('http://www.google.com')
    return {"Status":"Success"}
```

We even tried

```
webbrowser.open('http://example.com')
```

**We are getting the response but we aren't getting any pop-up window or webpage is not getting open.**

What I am really trying to do is display 2 to 3 **response cards using Lex** and when the user **clicks on one of them**, **I want to open a webpage** based on the choice which I want to do **using fulfillment through AWS Lambda**.

Comment: The Lambda function is running on a remote server, not your local computer, so I'm not sure how you would possibly expect this to work.

Comment: Are you invoking the lambda via apigateway from your web browser?

Comment: Hi @Mark.B. I agree that it is running on a remote server. What I am trying to do is like integrating AWS Lex and Lambda and using Lex we are posting response cards in Chatbot. Once the user clicks the response card in Chatbot I want to open a webpage based on the user's choice.

Comment: @cementblocks. No I am invoking using AWS Lex.

Comment: Did you get the solution @sriharan ?

Comment: It is definitely possible to invoke web browsers to open but you would need some sort of client on your users side to do the work. if you have a client already established, then perhaps a lambda could be used to trigger the client to open the browser.